# Why my following .htaccess rules is showing "Internal Server Error" message?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Well, I am using following `.htaccess` rules on my website but when I load the website it's showing me error message :

> **Internal Server Error**

**.htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase http://demo..com/

ErrorDocument 404 http://demo.mysite.com/not-found.php
ErrorDocument 500 http://demo.mysite.com/not-found.php


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ http://demo.mysite.com/menu-details.php?city=$1&mid=$2&title=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ http://demo.mysite.com/booking.php?city=$1&mid=$2&title=$3&action=$4 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ http://demo.mysite.com/city.php?city=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**Note :**

Currently I am using sub-domain (**demo.mysite.com**) to test it. Later I will use without sub-domain (**mysite.com**)

Comment: You need to check your apache log which is always the first thing to find out errors. at first glance though, that's an invalid RewriteBase. it doesn't take a URL it needs to be a directory. `RewriteBase /` OR `RewriteBase /subfolder/`

Comment: exactly :) You are right. It should be `/`